# UITextView making isScrolledEnabled removes right contentInset

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uitextview

I have a very simple implementation of a UITextView in my app. I have applied contentInset from all four sides, but when I make isScrolledEnabled false right contentInset goes away. With isScrolledEnabled true contentInset works fine. Can you please help me solve this ?
I am aware about textContainerInset and it works just fine but I don't want to use it. It is causing other things to break in my app.
Here is the sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        setupTextView()
        setupContraints()
    }
    
    private func setupTextView() {
        textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "Swift is a powerful and intuitive programming language for iOS, iPadOS, macOS, tvOS, and watchOS."
        textView.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)
        textView.contentInset = .init(top: 25, left: 25, bottom: 25, right: 25)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.addSubview(textView)
    }
    
    private func setupContraints() {
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
        textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of giving height and width use topAnchor, leadingAnchor, trailingAnchor and bottomAnchor

Comment: I did try that. Doesn't work.

Comment: @FE_Tech - the issue is: *`.contentInset` doesn't work that way with a `UITextView`.* To offer help, we need more information. What "breaks" when you use `textContainerInset`? Why are you using a text view instead of a label? etc...